# Default file transmission mode in FtpWebRequest

Tags: vb.net

Could you please let me know what is default file transmission mode in FtpWebRequest class in vb.net

below is sample

```
                   Dim request As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("ftp:// <ftp:///> " + _ds.Tables .Rows (2).ToString() + "/inbox/" + File), FtpWebRequest)
```

Currently we have not set active or passive mode of file transmission.
I just want to know that by default which is mode of file transmission used by this class.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft's Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.usepassive(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **FtpWebRequest.UsePassive Property**
>
> Property Value Type: System.Boolean
>
> false if the client application's data transfer process listens for a connection on the data port; otherwise, true if the client should initiate a connection on the data port. The default value is **true**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
so it means that if FtpWebRequest.UsePassive property is not set in code.
so it's default value will be true

Comment: yes, when you call "New FtpWebrequest" UsePassive will initialize to True by default